# Python Pandas drop the last row showing none

Tags: python, pandas

I have a def where it is pulling data from a CSV file and only showing a certain row & column. The issue I am having is when printing it adds a "none" row at the end.

---

```
def last_3rd_price():
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    row_start = df1.index[-3]
    row_end = df1.index[-3]
    last_3rd_price = df1.loc[row_start:row_end, 'Price']
            
    for price in last_3rd_price:
        print(price)
             
print(last_3rd_price())
```

---

## Data:

```
7129.32 Dec-15-2019 12:32:37
7129.32 Dec-15-2019 12:32:43
7129.32 Dec-15-2019 12:33:11
7129.26 Dec-15-2019 12:34:35
7129.26 Dec-15-2019 12:34:40
7129.26 Dec-15-2019 12:35:15
7129.26 Dec-15-2019 12:35:33
7127.56 Dec-15-2019 12:42:51
7128.43 Dec-15-2019 12:44:39
```

---

Here is the output:

7129.26

None

I would like to know how to get rid of the last none line. I have tried to use drop() & dropna() with no success

Comment: can you just slice it with [:-1]

Comment: Show us your data, and read the Pandas docs. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I have added the data in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re printing the result of the function, which is None, as it returns nothing.

You should have the function return a value, and fix those names.

Comment: Such an easy solution, I was banging my head about this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Is it "None" (string) or `None` you have in there? I believe `None` will be replaced by `np.NaN`. I think you have is "None" (string). 
Try this:

`df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()`

Comment: I tried this however it still returns the last line as None